# Jscheme or lisp !! comparing character

Tags: lisp

How can i check if the first element of a list is equal to some character

I tried this code but i didn't work

```
(= (car lis) 'f)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Clojure `(= (first list) \f)`

Comment: Do you really mean "character", or do you actually mean "symbol"? They're typically not the same thing; `'f` is "the symbol `f`", whereas `#\f` is "the character `f`" (in Common Lisp, at least). You generally want to compare, store and deal with them differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Common lisp you use `eq` for equality

```
(eql (car list) #\f)
```

Comment: I suspect that the question-asker actually means "symbol", not "character". But, in neither case is = a suitable equality comparator.

Comment: `eq` is not defined usefully for characters.  Use `eql` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Lisp `=` is used for numeric comparison, while general-purpose comparison operators are different variants of `equal` (in CL there are four ones: `eq` for pointer comparison, `eql` for comparison of atoms, `equal` for comparison of structures and `equalp`, which is like `equal` with string collation - see: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node74.html).